# Android Studio Emulator is running but but never goes beyond "Android Logo"

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-emulator

I am facing this problem that my Android Studio emulator is running but it never goes beyond the "**Android logo**" in booting up.

Please help me out with this problem, it's urgent!

I do not know how to resolve this problem.

[image: Emulator Image]

Comment: How long is "never"? It takes a lot of time to start this emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think your memory is not enough to load the emulator settings (screen density etc). You should try a lighter version.